# How to write select query for pipe "|" separated values in a column?

Tags: php, mysql

### I edited the post for the real problem

I tried to make a movie website. 
I have a **movie** table

```
id, moviename,  actorsid
1,  movie1,     1|2|3
2,  movie2,     1|5|4
```

And i have a **actors** table

```
id, actorname
1,  actor1
2,  actor2
3,  actor3
```

I want to display all actors movies, so i made a SELECT query in `movie` table, with the actor id that it had

```sql
SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE actors_id IN('4')
```

run successfully if the movie has i actor id only

```sql
SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE actors_id LIKE '%4%'
```

run successfully if i don't have any other id contain 4.. like 41 or 14 or 214

Comment: It return's all the value wich contains 1. PS you are open to SQL injection, consider to use preparement statements.

Comment: Not a good idea to multiple value in one row...you should have ONE usersid value by row and it would be easiest to do your query !

Comment: Changing the database structure would be the best option, failing that if you had a comma separated list - you could use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Please add a serious example ... what's your columns, what's your data ? Give example with inserts statements, we don't understand anything here...

Comment: FIND_IN_SET will not work with separator as "|" pipes. It works well with comma

Comment: @SureshKamrushi at least if OP still want to use single column to save multiple values (instead of normalizing table structure), changing delimiter to comma seems more feasible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
you can try something like below:

```
SELECT * FROM `TB` WHERE 
  usersid REGEXP '^31\\|' OR
  usersid REGEXP '\\|31$' OR
  usersid REGEXP '\\|31\\|'
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b88de5/22

Please test all scenario before you implement.

**Option 2:**  You can use FIND_IN_SET after replacing pipe with comma like below:

```
SELECT * FROM `TB` WHERE FIND_IN_SET("31",replace(usersid,"|",","))
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b88de5/6

Comment: I think it will match all rows containing string 31 such as `31999|..|..`, `..|..|99931`, and `..|993199|...`

Comment: you need to escape "|" for each one (start, middle and at the end).. somehow it is not working.. so i ask test it before you use it.

Comment: In fact, your first option won't work as expected ! In your example on sqlfiddle if we replace 31 by 9, supposing we are looking for movies with actor id = 9. It will return the one row : 30|28|29, which is obviously not a movie with the actor id 9... Second option is the only good answer here !

Comment: @Gosfly: In my earlier comment i mention that string need to be escape for Pipe char. No Issues...Updated my answer to escape and search in all scenarios. Fiddle links is also updated.